# Sending partials from keystone.js for use with ui.view

Tags: angular-ui-router, keystonejs

Been trying to get my head around this, but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.

So I want to set up keystone, but want to use angular on the front end, and I want to avoid reloading the page every time.

Got angular running quite fine and pretty quickly. But now I am trying to set up the routes on the backend for the partials, and while I can manage to get them set up to answer, I can not get them to just send the partial, whatever I do it sends the whole page back to me. with html, body, head.

So far I have managed to figure out that I need a route, so imported my uiview directory and added the following route:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);

// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views'),
    uiviews: importRoutes('/uiviews'), 
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.get('/uiviews/index',routes.uiviews.index);
    app.get('/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
    app.get('/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
    app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
    app.all('/contact', routes.views.contact);

    // NOTE: To protect a route so that only admins can see it, use the requireUser middleware:
    // app.get('/protected', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.protected);

};
```

I think what is happening is that the pre compiler (    keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);) gets hold of it and wraps it all the way it thinks it is suppose to, but I'm not certain.

I even tried to create a uiviews.js in ./routes with just my uiroute, but that gives me 404 errors

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);



// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    uiviews: importRoutes('/uiviews'), 
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    console.log('uiroutes added');
    app.get('/uiview/index',routes.uiviews.index);

    // NOTE: To protect a route so that only admins can see it, use the requireUser middleware:
    // app.get('/protected', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.protected);

};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out what I was missing.

Technically it is not keystone.js that controls what is sent, it is handlebars. This might be obvious to everyone but me.

However, the trick is to tell handlebars not to include the layout, which is done using {layout: false}. So my uiview route looks like this (last little line does the magic):

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
  console.log("request for index received");
  var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
    locals = res.locals;
    console.log(locals);

  // Render the view
    console.log(view)

  view.render('uiviews/index', {layout: false});
};
```

with the index.js router looking like this:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);

// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views'),
    uiviews: importRoutes('/uiviews'), 
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    console.log('index added');
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);   
    app.get('/partners', routes.views.partners);
    app.get('/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
    app.get('/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
    app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
    app.get('/philosophy', routes.views.philosophy)
    app.get('/socialmedia', routes.views.socialmedia)
    app.all('/contact', routes.views.contact);
    app.get('/uiviews/index', routes.uiviews.index)

    // NOTE: To protect a route so that only admins can see it, use the requireUser middleware:
    // app.get('/protected', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.protected);

};
```

And now you can call [host]/uiviews/index and only receive a partial route.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Express question and not of keystone.Js.
You have not said which router you want partially. and neither shared rendering code of that handler.

Any way  Make sure that the template you are using does **not include any other template**. particularly default.jade

Comment: I am planning to use ui.router, but I haven't even tried implementing that section yet, as I can't get the partials served. I removed the handlebars {{{ body }}} section and added <ui-view></ui-view>, but the issue is that if I call 127.0.0.1:3000/uiview/index, I do not get my index view, I get keystones index file generated. I think the issue is that any route in index.js keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);, but I need a way to either tell it not to do that for some routes or add another router without breaking keystone

Comment: You are wrong in doubting initLocal. it does not do anything .

Comment: So removed that, and you seem to be right, it does not do anything, but if I call my /uiviews/index, I still get the whole page rendered, and not just the part of it in the file, is there any way I can tell keystone not to render the default view on a call?

Comment: are you including any other template in you template file. like include default.jade